# Efficient and Accurate way to add items into a TList

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have 2 lists and the entities of the those lists have some IDs for instance

`Client.ID,` where ID is a property of Client anf then I have `PopulationClient.ID`, where ID is a property of the class PopulationClient. So I have two Lists

```
TList<Client> clients = clientsHelper.GetAllClients();
TList<PopulationClient> populationClients = populationHelper.GetAllPopulationClients();
```

So then I have a temp List

```
TList<Client> temp_list = new TList<Client>();
```

So the problem i am having is doing this efficiently and correctly. This is what I have tried.. but I am not getting the correct results

```
foreach(PopulationClient pClients in populationClients)
{
    foreach(Client client in clients)
     {
         if(pClients.ID != client.ID  &&  !InTempList(temp_list, pClients.ID))
         {
             temp_list.Add(client);
         }
     }
}

public bool InTempList(TList<Client> c, int id)
{
    bool IsInList = false;
    foreach(Client client in c)
    {
        if(client.ID == id)
        {
              IsInList = true;
        }
    }    
   return IsInList;
}
```

So while I am trying to do it right I can not come up with a good way of doing it, this is not returning the correct data because in my statement in the first loop at the top,at some point one or more is different to the otherone so it adds it anyways. What constraints do you think I should check here  so that I only end up with a list of Clients that are in population clients but not in Clients?.

For instance population clients would have 4 clients and Clients 2, those 2 are also in population clients but I need to get a list of population clients not in Clients.

ANy help or pointers would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, let's concentrate on getting the right results, and then we'll optimize.

Consider your nested loops: you will get too many positives, because in most (pclient, client) pairs the IDs wouldn't match. I think you wanted to code it like this:

```
foreach(PopulationClient pClients in populationClients)
{
     if(!InTempList(clients, pClients.ID) && !InTempList(temp_list, pClients.ID))
     {
         temp_list.Add(client);
     }
}
```

Now for the efficiency of that code: `InTempList` uses linear search through lists. This is not efficient - consider using structures that are faster to search, for example, hash sets.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you're looking for, here is a way to do it with LINQ...

```
tempList = populationList.Where(p => !clientList.Any(p2 => p2.ID == p.ID));
```

Comment: I don't think that's his intent, since tempList items are of type Client, not PopulationClient

Answer (score 0):

Just to offer another LINQ-based answer... I *think* your intent is to populate tempList based on all the items in 'clients' (returned from GetAllClients) that don't show up (based on 'ID" value) in the populationClients collection.

If that's the case, then I'm going to assume that populationClients is sufficiently large to warrant doing a hash-based looked (if it's less than 10 items, the linear scan may not be a big deal, for instance).

So we want a fast-lookup version of all the ID values from the populationClients collection:

```
var populationClientIDs = populationClients.Select(pc => pc.ID);
var populationClientIDHash = new HashSet(populationClientIDs);
```

Now that we have the ID values we want to ignore in a fast lookup data structure, we can then use that as a filter for the clients:

```
var filteredClients = clients.Where(c => populationClientIDHash.Contains(c.ID) == false);
```

Based on the usage/need, you could either populate the tempList from 'filteredClients', or do a ToList, or whatever.